# sigma.js : Is there a way to drag one node individually

Tags: sigma.js

I tried to drag a node individually by getting the mouse position, by it seems to be catched by the whole graph grab behavior.
The properties of the selected nodes are properly modified but the other nodes are moving together, even if I set n.x and n.y.

Here's my attempt :
http://jsfiddle.net/blt909/yhk3b/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var sigRoot = document.getElementById('sig');
   var sigInst = sigma.init(sigRoot).position(0, 0, 1);
   var mousePos = {};
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
       var $div = $("#sig");
       mousePos = {
           x: e.pageX,
           y: e.pageY
       };
   });   

    function onNodeDown(evt) {
        var sigmajs = evt.target;
        var nodeId = evt.content[0];
        sigmajs.iterNodes(function(n){
            n.size = 5;
            n.color = "#0000FF";
            n.displayX = mousePos.x;
            n.displayY = mousePos.y;
            console.log(n);
       },[nodeId]);    

       sigmajs.draw(2,2,2, false);

       sigmajs.refresh();
    };

    sigInst.graphProperties({
        minNodeSize: 2,
        maxNodeSize: 5
    });

    sigInst.addNode('000',{
        label: '000',
        color: '#000000',
          x: Math.random() * 100,
          y: Math.random() * 100
    }).addNode('111',{
        label: '111',
        color: '#111111',
          x: Math.random() * 100,
          y: Math.random() * 100
    }).addNode('222',{
        label: '222',
        color: '#222222',
          x: Math.random() * 100,
          y: Math.random() * 100
    }).addEdge('111222','111','222')
      .addEdge('111000','111','000');

      sigInst.bind('downnodes',onNodeDown);

      sigInst.draw();
  })
```

Did anybody tried the same trick on sigma.js?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi, did you solve it this issue?

Comment: I didn't find any solution for now but I've not tried the new version sigma.js published between my question and now...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The new sigma.js has a `dragNodes` plugin [sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/master/plugins/sigma.plugins.dragNodes/sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js) but it only works in canvas, just include the plugin file and pass the sigma object:

```html
<script src="./plugins/sigma.plugins.dragNodes/sigma.plugins.dragNodes.js"></script>
```

```js
let dragListener = sigma.plugins.dragNodes(sigInst, sigInst.renderers[0])
```

Comment: As soon as I will migrate my app on the new version, i'll try your tip.

Comment: Okay this is very old, but maybe someone can help. How do I include this with jsfiddle? I don't have a programming background so I run into a wall here, because its apparently obvious, and never mentioned.